# Updating the values from a table in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-table

I'm building a simple React App and I have a component called Clients.
In this component there is a Form to add new clients (ClientForm component) and a Table that shows all my clients that I have in my DB (ClientList component). I can insert and delete from my DB (MongoDB), the problem is to update the clients.

Here is my ClientList.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

import ClientItem from './ClientItem';
import './ClientList.css';

const ClientList = props => {
    if (props.items.length === 0) {
        return (
          <div>
              <h2>Nenhum cliente registrado.</h2>
          </div>
        );
    }

    return (
      <Table responsive bordered hover variant="dark">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Nome</th>
                  <th>Telefone</th>
                  <th>CPF</th>
                  <th>Cidade/UF</th>
                  <th>Ações</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {props.items.map(client => (
              <ClientItem
                callback={props.callback}
                key={client._id}
                id={client._id}
                phone={client.phone}
                name={client.name}
                cpf={client.cpf}
                city={client.city}
                UF={client.UF}
              />
            ))}
          </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
};

export default ClientList;
```

And here is my ClientItem.js

```
    import React from 'react';

import api from '../../shared/services/api';
import Button from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Button';

const ClientItem = props => {

    const editHandler = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const id = event.target.id;

            await api.put('/clients/update/' + id + '');
            alert('Cliente Atualizado Com Sucesso');
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert('Erro ao Atualizar Cliente');
        }
    }

    const deleteHandler = async event => {
        try {
            let id = props.id
            const res = await api.delete('/clients/delete/'+id+'');
            alert('Deletado com Sucesso');
            props.callback();
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert('Erro ao Excluir Cliente');
        }
    }

    return (
        <tr id={props.id}>
            <td>{props.name}</td>
            <td>{props.phone}</td>
            <td>{props.cpf}</td>
            <td>{props.city}/{props.UF}</td>
            <td><Button id={props.id} type="submit" onClick={editHandler}>Edit</Button><Button danger onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</Button></td>
        </tr>
    );
};

export default ClientItem;
```

My problem is: Each Client is a row in my table, how can I get all the data in this specific row that I clicked the button Edit. (The Delete button is working fine).

I tried making every `<td>` have an `<input>` inside, but I can't make every `<tr>` a `<form>`

Comment: upon cliking on table row, you have to navigate to a component where you have a form to update the object.In that component you get id form route and fetch object and update it

Answer (score 0):

Try Passing the props to the eventhandler method as a second parameter

```
 import React from 'react';
 import api from '../../shared/services/api';
 import Button from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Button';

const ClientItem = props => {

const editHandler = async (event,funcProps) => {
    event.preventDefault();
   console.log(funcProps);{/* Destruture the props here the way you want */}
    try {
        const id = event.target.id;

        await api.put('/clients/update/' + id + '');
        alert('Cliente Atualizado Com Sucesso');
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert('Erro ao Atualizar Cliente');
    }
}


return (
    <tr id={props.id}>
        <td>{props.name}</td>
        <td>{props.phone}</td>
        <td>{props.cpf}</td>
        <td>{props.city}/{props.UF}</td>
        <td><Button id={props.id} type="submit" onClick={(event)=>editHandler(event,props)}>Edit</Button><Button danger onClick={deleteHandler}>Delete</Button></td>
    </tr>
);};export default ClientItem;
```

Comment: But that way I get the initial value in the function. I want to be able to edit then inside the td and get the new value

Comment: This should pass the data of the item you clicked on to the eventhandler function rather than the initial props , have you tried it?